# Built-in Like doesn't trigger Facebook notification

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We have implemented the built-in open graph action "like" in our applications, following [facebook tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/).

In our app:

1. Users can **"offer"** (action) an **"asset"** (object).
2. Then a Friend can **"like"** (action) that **"asset"** (object).

Now when that happen a Facebook notification is supposed to show up on User's facebook.

> When a friend views the user’s “recipe” within the context of the social recipe app, and clicks on an associated “like button” that also publishes a built-in Like action to Open Graph, a Facebook notification would be generated.

Like this one:

[image: Facebook notification]

As facebook explains, we added the action "offer" as **"creation action"** on the "asset" object page:

[image: creation action]

> To enable Facebook Notifications when publishing built-in Like actions, configure a "creation action" for the object representing the user-generated content

But still nothing happens. What are we doing wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason for this problem:

"This Facebook notification will only appear to a user when the person who “liked” the object is the user’s Facebook friend, this friend’s app activity is visible to the user, and the Open Graph object was “created” by the user through a “creation action”."

Please make sure that the person liking your object meets the first two criteria, before expecting a jewel notification to appear.